# How to fix Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input?

Tags: reactjs, post, file-upload, form-data, cloudinary

So I want to upload a file to Cloudinary using React but I get an `Upload.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` in my `let json = await res.json();` line. How can I fix this?

```
class Upload extends React.Component {
  processFile = async e => {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append("file", file);
    formdata.append("cloud_name", "dvrmt2oir");
    formdata.append("upload_preset", "wco0c7sr");

    let res = await fetch(
      "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dvrmt2oir/image/upload",
      {
        method: "post",
        mode: "cors",
        body: formdata
      }
    );

    let json = await res.json();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.secure_url));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Upload</h3>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.processFile} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class Upload extends React.Component {
  processFile = async e => {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append("file", file);
    formdata.append("cloud_name", "dvrmt2oir");
    formdata.append("upload_preset", "wco0c7sr");

    let res = await fetch(
      "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dvrmt2oir/image/upload",
      {
        method: "post",
        mode: "cors",
        body: formdata
      }
    );

    let json = await res.json();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.secure_url));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Upload</h3>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.processFile} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Upload />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

And it worked. Can you please provide the image that you tried to upload?